# ResultSet always return null even when data is present?

Tags: java, jdbc

The following code snippet always returns `null`. Can anyone please tell me what is the mistake? I've tried the query in the database and the rows do exist.

```
public int[] getStats(String fabrik) {

    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer(
        "SELECT TRAINS_IN_USE, FREE_TRAINS, LOADED_TRAINS, LATE_TRAINS, DELIVERING_TRAINS, INCOMING_TRAINS, PALLETS_IN_STORAGE FROM GRAPHSTATS where log_time like '%14-NOV-19 11:24:57%' ");
    // log_time = (select max(log_time) from graphstats
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    if (fabrik != null) {
        sql.append(" AND fabrik = ?");
    }
    String sq = sql.toString();
    try {
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sq);
        if (fabrik != null) {
            pstmt.setString(1, fabrik);
        }
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            return new int[] {rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getInt(3), rs.getInt(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6), rs.getInt(7)};
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Logger.error(
            this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "." + CurrentMethodName.getCurrentMethodName() + " Exception: " + e.getMessage(), null);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it). Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Your question text said *"...code snippet always returns."* Based on your question title, when I fixed the formatting and put the question at the top, I added `null` to the end of that sentence. Please use the "edit" link if you really meant just "returns." and not "returns `null`."

Comment: If there were any matching rows, that code would work. (There are things you might change, such as using try-with-resources -- [like this](https://pastebin.com/RMUJBNne) -- but it would work.) I suspect the problem is that you're trying to match against a `DATE` or `DATETIME` column or similar, and the tool you used to check the query against the database is using a different date/time format than the code is, so the `LIKE` works in your query tool but not in the real code, because the `DATE`/`DATETIME` is being converted to a different character string.

Comment: I'd also suspect that there is something wrong with your connection if you're saying that the exact same query is working in your db editor

Comment: `executeQuery` **never** returns `null`. It can only return a possibly empty result set or throw an exception, null is not possible (except in buggy drivers). You may want to clarify your actually problem. Please make sure you post a [mre], including necessary DDL and example data and make sure to specify the database you use.

Comment: I suspect the result is empty, `rs` doesn't have a `next` (i.e.: `rs.next() = false`), therefore it skips that `if` statement and executes the "default" `return null` at the end. Have you tried the same query directly on the database?

Comment: (As @T.J.Crowder pointed) Maybe there is something wrong with your query and the way you run it. I mean, when you run the query in your Database Management it can be influenced by timezone and date formating, and when you run the query in your application the JDBC does the job. I see that you have a WHERE criteria filtering data in the log_time COLUMN using a literal string. Try to use real timestamp data type or format and convert the column for the correct data type and use the BETWEEN criteria.